# Can't change the language when phone screen locked

Tags: lock-screens

I am using Samsung Galaxy Core. I have given Password to my mobile in English. Today for some reason I changed my Language to TAMIL and forgot to change back to English. My Phone got locked when i try to give the password the keyboard appears in Tamil and I can't do anything. How can I change it

Comment: Press and hold the spacebar to change the keyboard language. (as shown on [this instruction](https://videotron.tmtx.ca/faqs/item/?lc=en&p=samsung_galaxycorelte&a=changing_the_keyboard_language))

Comment: This works if the keyboard remains the default Samsung Keyboard. Other keyboards may, or typically may not, have this capability. Hackers Keyboard, my preference, specifically does NOT. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Press the space button and hold the English language, and other languages will appear. Choose the language as you like and it will change the language.

Comment: That only works with the default keyboard (e.g Samsung). Third party keyboards usually miss this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered on Samsung. Then log in to your account using other computer. And reset Samsung mobile.

Now first tell me have enabled find my device on your mobile. If yes then log in to your account on any device and you an unlock your devices.
Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get a wired keyboard and plug it into the phone using OTG. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that I was unable to login into my phone due to the default language (keyboard layout) being non-English. The bad thing is when you try to change the language preference (by pressing space and hold) it again asks you for the password. The problem repeats itself. I solved this problem in this way:

1. I login into "safe mode" first (follow [the link to the official Samsung Support](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-restart-my-device-if-it-is-frozen-or-not-responding/)).

2. Then I changed the default keyboard layout into Samsung keyboard (which is English)
3. Then I restarted it. This time the keyboard is English.